# MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations in Production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-query

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

let connection = {};

async function connect() {
  try {
    if (connection.isConnected) {
      console.log('Connected');
      return;
    }
    if (mongoose.connections.length > 0) {
      connection.isConnected = mongoose.connections[0].readyState;
      if (connection.isConnected === 1) {
        console.log("Previous Connection Established");
        return;
      }
      await mongoose.disconnect();
    }
    const db = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
    console.log("New Connection");
    connection.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connecting to database:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

async function disconnect() {
  if (connection.isConnected) {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      await mongoose.disconnect();
      connection.isConnected = false;
    } else {
      console.log("Still Connected");
    }
  }
}

const db = { connect, disconnect };
export default db;
```

This is my db functions that i am using in nextjs and mongoose but constantly receiving this error.
I have tried lot of solution but this error is constant.

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  await db.connect();
  const products = await Product.find().lean();
  await db.disconnect();
  return {
    props: {
      Products: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products)),
    },
  };
}
```

Thats how i am calling mongodb function

Please tell me where i am wrong or how can it be fixed.

I tried using digitalocean integrated mongodb servers but they were not throwing this error. Mongodb official website clusters are having this issue.
I am using mongodb serverless instance and everytime getting this error. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Opening/Closing connections are expensive operations, you don't need to close connections every time, except when app is shutting down.

Mongoose module is a singleton instance that handles the connection pool for you, so you can import and share it in your modules.

```js
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';

  async function init() {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI); //set your connection string
    } catch (err) {
      //if connection was not successfull, shutdown app
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }

  async function App() {
    const connection =  await db.init();
    const User = mongoose.model('User');
    const user = await User.findOne().exec();
    console.log(user);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please let me know that I have lots of requests like this, shall I keep all of the connections open as you mentioned above or if not. How to know which connection to close or which to keep open?

Comment: you don't need to worry about connections. Mongoose will handle everything for you. Once connected (i.e., connection string is valid), you're good. My advice is to ensure to call initialization of mongoose before the web server. So you will be safe from race conditions.

Comment: Sorry brother but this is not helping. Initialization of mongoose is called prior of web server only. But still its acting weird and I am not able to debug and get whats failing the server again and again 
I somewhere believe its because of disconnect function